# non-separable "heat equation"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

I am trying to solve the following PDE:
$$
\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 f(t,x)}{\partial x^2}x(1-x)
$$
with $(t,x)\in [0,1]^2$ and boundary conditions $f(1,\cdot)=f(\cdot,1)=0$. Is there a non-trivial solution to this? 
I tried to separate the variables but one of the boundary conditions gets violated in that case. Specifically, if we guess a non-trivial solution takes the form $f(t,x)=F(t)G(x)$, then the PDE becomes
$$
\frac{F'(t)}{F(t)}=\frac{G''(x)}{G(x)}x(1-x)=-c
$$
which must hold for any $(t,x)$ pair in the interior of domain. Hence, the fractions equal some real number $-c$. The general solutions for the resulting ODEs are $$F(t)=Ae^{-ct}$$ and $$G(t)=Bx^y(1-x)^z$$ where $y,z$ are constants that depend on $c$ and $A, B, c$ are yet to be determined constants. But then $$f(1,x)=ABe^{-c}x^y(1-x)^z \neq 0$$ for $x<1$ unless $AB=0$ which makes the solution trivial.

Comment: Are those really the boundary conditions you have? The data at the final time and along just one edge?

Comment: Yes. The condition came out of an HJB equation I am trying to solve. The problem is solvable when $t\in \mathbb{R}_+$ since the entire problem becomes $t$-independent (time-independent in my case) so the LHS of the original PDE above is just 0.

Comment: The general solution you've written is wrong. The second equation is $$x(1-x)X''+cX=0$$
Here you let $X(x)=xS(x)$
then
$$X''=2S'+xS''$$
and the equation becomes
$$x(1-x)S''+2(1-x)S'+cS=0$$
Compare with the hypergeometric equation
$$x(1-x)S''+(\gamma-(\alpha+\beta+1)x)S'-\alpha\beta{S}=0$$
You have
$$\gamma=2$$
and 
$$\beta^{2}-\beta-c=0$$
$$\alpha=1-\beta=\frac{-1\mp\sqrt{1+4c}}{2}$$ So, the solution is given in terms of sum of two Hypergeometric functions, this, however does not solve your problem, but just for reference.

Comment: @tsm : They are an infinity of solutions because the specified boundary conditions are not sufficient to determine a unique solution. For example, if you find a solution $F(x,t)$ , then all $C\,F(x,t)$ are solutions agreeing to the boundary conditions, with any constant C. Moreover, this isn't exhaustive. Before answering to the question, it should be necessary to review the wording of the problem to make it well-posed. By the way, the title should be corrected because the PDE is separable.